# Start SSH in isolated rescue.target?

Tags: boot, ssh, systemd, rescue-mode

I'm planning a system upgrade from Eoan to Focal on a remote machine where I only have SSH access. I've previously dealt with broken packages causing the system to boot into rescue mode, so I want to ensure whatever happens I can keep my access to the server. To further secure the process, I'm doing a rehearsal using a local virtual machine running the target system.

With my knowledge in Ubuntu, I did the following tasks beforehand:

- `systemctl edit ssh.service` and insert `DefaultDependencies=no` to [Unit] section and `WantedBy=rescue.target` to [Install] section, then `systemctl enable ssh.service`. Systemd reports "created symbolic link".
- `systemctl edit rescue-ssh.target` and insert `WantedBy=rescue.target` to [Install] section, then `systemctl enable rescue-ssh.target`.

Then I edited grub to enable boot menu, `update-grub` then `systemctl reboot`, and use `e` to edit the default entry. I scrolled down to the first `linux` line and appended `rescue` and booted this entry with Ctrl-X, which led to this screen:

[image: rescue mode]

Everything seems fine here as I can SSH into this VM right at this point.

---

**My question begins:**

I tried again in a different way to test SSH availability in rescue mode. First I booted the system normally into graphical mode (with GNOME and whatever), started a terminal and ran `systemctl isolate rescue.target`. I see the same prompt text again, but when trying to SSH into the VM, I got the following result:

```
ubuntu@WSL:~ $ ssh root@vmwares
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.2.5' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Timeout, server 192.168.2.5 not responding.
255|ubuntu@WSL:~ $
```

Running `systemctl status ssh.service` highlighted the following text:

> pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)

Restarting `systemd-logind.service` makes no difference. Going back to graphical interface with `systemctl isolate default.target` brings everything back to normal again.

**Question:** Why can't I login to SSH when the rescue target is isolated from graphical.target? How to I resolve this?

I think there's something to do with "isolating targets", but apparently things have gone beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?